# Trouble running java program

Tags: java, classpath, javac, noclassdeffounderror

I 'm trying to run a simple java program but I keep getting a NoClassDeffoundError. My directory structure is as follows;

```
/src/atlasAPI/AtlasService.java
/src/DatabaseClient.java

/lib/<some jar files>

/bin/DatabaseClientTest.class
/bin/AtlasService.class
```

The DatabaseClientTest class has the main method.

How do I run the program from the command line?

Comment: How are you running it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include in your classpath every class that is needed, including your jars in the "lib" directory and your .class files.

```
java -cp lib/*:bin DatabaseClientTest
```

The "-cp" is the option to include a classpath.  "lib/*" means all jar files in the "lib" directory", and "bin" means all class files in the "bin" directory.  The ":" separates multiple parts of the path, assuming you're on Unix/Linux.

Here's the link to the [Java Tutorial on Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

Comment: Do i run this from inside the bin folder?

Comment: I had assumed that you are running your code from the directory that contains the "src", "lib", and "bin" directories, so that's how I constructed the command line.

Comment: Thanks!, i spent close to an hour for this issue since I usually use eclipse. Upvoted and approved ;)